# SQL query to group a column and ignore null values

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table like:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1          a
1     b          
1                c
2     e   
2          f  
2                g
```

I need to write a query which will have the output like this

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1     a     b   c
2     e     f   g
```

I am using oracle 10g

Comment: What happens if there is more than one entry in Col2 for the same value in Col1?

Comment: i tried group by the Col1 but couldnt use it as i need to display all the columns

Comment: @Mark There will only one entry in Col2 for the same value in Col1

Comment: @Prash let's see your code

Comment: @Mark why would you need to see the code for this?

Answer (score 12):

If you only have one value per column, then you might be able to use an aggregate function:

```
select 
  col1,
  max(col2) col2,
  max(col3) col3,
  max(col4) col4
from yourtable
group by col1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5b14c/1)

The result is:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
-----------------------------
|    1 |    b |    a |    c |
|    2 |    e |    f |    g |
```

Comment: @Prash You are welcome. If you find this answer helpful or any of the other answers to your questions, then be sure to accept via the checkmark on the left of the answer. It helps future visitors to the site know the answer that was selected and you get rep for accepting. See [how does accepting answers work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more details. :)